# Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have :

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Name");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("key");
        $client->setClientId("id");
        $client->setClientSecret("codesecret");
        $client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"));
        $client->setRedirectUri("https://www.example.com/oauth2callback");
```

And I have this error "Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'", how can I fix this? And I don't know how to get the token.

Comment: Are you replacing `Name` `key` `id` and `codesecret` with your own values when trying to run this? The OAuth2 endpoint expects you to have registered your application with Google first.

Comment: Yes I have replaced Name key and id with the good values, and I registered my application on Google first. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Did you delete the space in the client secret when you copy from developers console? Also, did you enable calendar api in console?

Comment: No space and yes the calendar api is enable.